# Why is GAMM fit so poor?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I have annual measurements of these 3 IDs and would like to visualise their overall trend (one curve) using R's `gamm` function in order to control for autocorrelation within each ID.

```
> head(dat)
  Time ID  Val
1    1 06 0.66
2    2 06 0.81
3    3 06 0.84
4    4 06 1.09
5    5 06 0.79
6    6 06 1.44

library(mgcv)

mod <- gamm(Val ~ s(Time),
                  random = list(ID = ~1), 
                  correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ Time | ID),
                  data = dat)

> summary(mod$gam)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
Val ~ s(Time)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value      Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.9853     0.1559   6.321 0.00000000178 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
        edf Ref.df     F p-value  
s(Time)   1      1 4.162  0.0427 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.151   
  Scale est. = 0.56236   n = 194

mod.fit <- data.frame(ID = dat$ID[complete.cases(dat$Val)],
                            Time = dat$Time[complete.cases(dat$Val)],
                            Val = dat$Val[complete.cases(dat$Val)],
                            fit = predict(mod$gam, type = "response"))

ggplot(mod.fit) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = Val, colour = ID)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Time, y = fit, group = ID))
```

However, I am suprised the fit is so "linear"? Am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(Time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                               11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
                               24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
                               37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
                               50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
                               63L, 64L, 65L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
                               12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
                               25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
                               38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
                               51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
                               64L, 65L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                               13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
                               26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
                               39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
                               52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
                               65L), ID = c("06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
                                            "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
                                            "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
                                            "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
                                            "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
                                            "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
                                            "06", "06", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
                                            "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
                                            "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
                                            "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
                                            "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
                                            "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
                                            "08", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                                            "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                                            "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                                            "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                                            "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
                                            "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10"
                               ), Val = c(0.66, 0.81, 0.84, 1.09, 0.79, 1.44, 0.52, 1.79, 1.24, 
                                          0.95, 0.6, 1.32, 1.48, 1.29, 1.83, 1.95, 1.4, 1.16, 0.81, 0.99, 
                                          0.59, 0, 0.36, 0.64, 0.38, 0.32, 0.34, 0.1, 0.46, 0.36, 0.18, 
                                          0.13, 0.33, 0.37, 0.26, 0.13, 0.36, 0.13, 0.52, 0.51, 0.73, 0.71, 
                                          1.27, 1, 1.5, 0.96, 0.44, 1.21, 0.91, 1.13, 0.63, 0.63, 0.58, 
                                          0.64, 0.75, 0.91, 1.11, 0.91, 0.96, 0.95, 0.61, 0.54, 0.62, 0.42, 
                                          0.54, 1.5, 1.75, 1.54, 1.71, 1.27, 1.65, 0.53, 0.58, 0.84, 1.41, 
                                          1.16, 1.45, 0.96, 0.61, 0.52, 0.69, 0.78, 1.06, 0.78, 0.6, 0.84, 
                                          0.53, 0.87, 0.63, 0.53, 0.53, 0.54, 0.31, 0.37, 0.21, 0.24, 0.3, 
                                          0.22, 0.33, 0.24, 0, 0.29, 0, 0.3, 0.29, 0.47, 0.67, 1.13, 1.52, 
                                          2.73, 1.39, 0.53, 1.1, 0.91, 0.94, 0.89, 0.85, 1.33, 0.94, 1.3, 
                                          1.24, 1.33, 1.69, 1.49, 0.76, 0.82, 0.44, 0.63, 0.44, 0.45, 0.74, 
                                          0.72, 1.32, 2.83, 2.16, 3.75, 3.08, 4.2, 4.4, 3.9, 2.35, 3.57, 
                                          2.94, 2.96, 3.28, 2.91, 3.59, 3.38, 2.1, 2.1, 1.4, 1.14, 2.04, 
                                          2.01, 1.13, 1.45, 1.31, 0.92, 0.97, 0.63, 1, 0.91, 0.54, 0.83, 
                                          0.68, 0.96, 0.77, 0.56, 0.74, 1, 1.27, 0.82, 1.85, 1.91, 1.56, 
                                          0.52, 0.27, 0.85, 0.78, 0.85, 0.45, 0.9, 0, 0.64, 1.1, 0.6, 0.42, 
                                          0.25, 0.28, 0.32, 0.57, 0.23, 0.18, 0.14, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                              -195L))
```

Comment: quick thoughts: (1) try increasing the maximum dimension (e.g. `s(Time,k=30)`); (2) the random effect only includes an among-ID shift in the intercept, doesn't allow for different curves by ID; (3) the random effects term is not going to work very well with only three groups - try comparing a simple `gam()` [with a time-by-ID interaction]

Comment: When you sat "poor" what aspect of the fit are you referring to? That line looks like quite a good fit to your three data-sets given that as @BenBolker points out you have forced a common slope.

Comment: I think OP wants more wiggliness from the smooth term, e.g. detecting the common peak around t=45 ...

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for the comments, yes, I have fitted GAMMs for other sets of data and for those the fitted curves follow the original series much more closely. So, according (2): How would I change that in the model formula? And should I? And according (3): How exactly would I fit the gam with "time-by-ID interaction"?

Comment: I may not be able to get back to this before this afternoon (at the earliest) ...  you could use a factor smooth (`s(Time, fac=ID, bs="fs")`, see `?smooth.construct.fs.smooth.spec` or a `by` argument `s(Time, by="ID")`

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to combine a temporal correlation model and a GAM with a time smoother. Currently the wiggliness is modelled by the correlation structure.

Comment: With just three subjects, you could do `dat$ID <- factor(dat$ID); mod <- gam(Val ~ ID + s(Time, by = ID),
            data = dat, select = TRUE)`. If you had more subjects, a random effects smoother might be sensible: `mod <- gam(Val ~ s(Time) + s(ID, Time, bs = "re") + s(ID, bs = "re"),
            data = dat, select = TRUE)`.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, the first one does however return a fit for each ID instead of one curve?

Comment: So, you really want to do population-level predictions based on only three subjects?

Comment: @Roland Re your random effects smoother, those `s(ID, Time, bs = 're')` are really just linear random effects (I guess slopes in this instance). Did you mean to suggest `bs = 'fs'`, which would give random smooths.

Comment: Further to @Roland's point about including both a smooth of time and a correlation structure, the issue is that these two components are often unidentifiable; strong autocorrelation about a simple linear trend or a wiggly trend and no autocorrelation are two ways you could describe the data. Unless you have a priori reason to constrain one of the two processes (say by saying the smooth is not very wiggly, or that the correlation parameter is small) then there is often little the model can do to separate these two processes.

Comment: @GavinSimpson So, is using `gam(Val ~ s(Time, bs = "fs"), correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ Time | ID)` sufficient to account for the random effect (i. e. for having annual data for a number of IDs)?

Comment: @beetroot No; you can't include `correlation` in a `gam()` model, it is ignored. I also don't think you should be trying to estimate a random effect (random smooth) from only 3 observations from the population. I would start with `gam(Val ~ ID + s(Time, by = ID), ....)`. You don;t need both a smoother and the CAR(1) typically, especially for such wiggly trends as are present in your data. Put another way, that linear trend you identified plus the CAR(1) can model a lot of the non-linearity in your data set. You can't model the non-linearity twice, once with a smoother and once with the CAR(1).

Comment: @beetroot Also, assuming you had more IDs (10 or more) then the random smoother would be `s(Time, ID, bs = 'fs')`, i.e. you need both a continuous variable (`Time)` and a factor (`ID`) to setu up the factor-smooth interaction basis.

Comment: @GavinSimpson OK cool, thanks. I've changed my design a bit and now have 15 IDs. Still wondering about one more question: Do I simply use `Val ~ s(Time, ID, bs = "fs")` or `Val ~ s(Time) + s(Time, ID, bs = "fs")`?

Comment: @beetroot it depends; the first doesn't have a common trend but individual smooths are pulled towards 0 and one another, the second has a common trend and difference smooths (the second `s()` in the model) are pulled towards 0 (and hence the common trend), but at the potential expense of greater uncertainty as there is concurvity between the global and individual smooths. If you want to dig into this more, colleagues and I have a paper we're about to submit which explores these models: https://github.com/noamross/mixed-effect-gams and see the `compiled_paper` folder for the rendered PDF.